# sourcing csh script does not set the path variable without Bad subtitute

Tags: path, csh

I am writing a simple script to source path variable as below:

```
#!/bin/csh
echo "setting path"
set path=($path /sbin:/mscc/apps)
```

However, the path variable does not change and remain the same. The csh shell does not have any errors/warnings.

If I add an invalid line, for example:

```
setenv PATH $PATH:sbin
```

It complains "Bad substitute." but the two path above are added. Why is it happening?

Comment: Are you executing the sample script and expecting your current (the parent) shell's $path to change?

Comment: Yes, I expect my current opened shell (from GNOME) to change the $path. I tried your answers with both ways and it is not working. The only time it works is when I add an invalid line at the end of the file (eg, like dummy text: ppp).

Comment: sourcing the script doesn't change the path?  Did you try using a space instead of a colon?

Comment: Yes, to eliminate the concern, I am setting only one path variable now which has the same result.

Comment: Can you edit a transcript of your session into your question, showing your initial path, your execution of the script, and the resulting path?

Answer (score 1):

I can only duplicate this if I *execute* such a script:

```
$ echo $path
/usr/local/bin /usr/bin /usr/local/sbin /usr/sbin

$ ./script.csh
setting path
$ echo $path
/usr/local/bin /usr/bin /usr/local/sbin /usr/sbin
```

If you instead *source* the script, you'll see different behavior:

```
$ source script.csh
setting path
$ echo $path
/usr/local/bin /usr/bin /usr/local/sbin /usr/sbin /sbin:/mscc/apps
```

(Perhaps you want `/sbin /mscc/apps` with a space instead of a colon separating the elements?)

Answer (score 1):

It is not the same to *run* a script and to `source` a script. 
When you *run* a script (with `./script.sh`) you are spawning a new process, which will execute the script. In the meantime, the shell process (the one where you wrote `./script.sh`) will wait until that other process finishes, and maybe capture the output.

The spawned process is able to modify its own environment (for example, the `path` variable) but not the one of his parent. When it finishes, that process will die, and the parent will keep having the same value in `path`.

What you want is the parent process to run `set path=($path /sbin:/mscc/apps)`. To do so, write `source ./script.sh` instead of `./script.sh`. In this case the line `#!/bin/csh` is not needed, since it is just a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these worked for me in csh on HPUX:

Version 1 (update $path):

```
#!/bin/csh
echo "setting path"
set path=($path:q /sbin /mscc/apps)
echo '==[ echo $PATH - updated/exported by csh ]=='
echo $PATH
echo '==[ echo $path ]=='
echo $path
echo '==[ foreach pdir ($path:q) ; echo $pdir ; end - $path is a list ]=='
foreach pdir ($path:q)
    echo $pdir
end
echo '==[ sub-process $PATH - updated PATH exported by csh automatically ]=='
perl -e 'print $ENV{PATH}."\n";'
```

Version 2 (update $PATH):

```
#!/bin/csh
echo "setting path"
setenv PATH "${PATH}:/sbin:/mscc/apps"
echo '==[ echo $PATH - exported by csh ]=='
echo $PATH
echo '==[ echo $path - updated from $PATH by csh ]=='
echo $path
echo '==[ foreach pdir ($path:q) ; echo $pdir ; end - $path is a list ]=='
foreach pdir ($path:q)
    echo $pdir
end
echo '==[ sub-process $PATH - updated PATH exported by csh automatically ]=='
perl -e 'print $ENV{PATH}."\n";'
```